# Remove the flash of unstyled content (FOUC) with Atom

Tags: performance, atom-editor, fouc

I've always experienced annoying [fouc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) with Atom on my MacBook Pro 13" (i5) which made me comeback to sublime text. I recently got myself a brand new MacBook Pro 15" (i7). And I still experience the same issue !

All I could find about it was this thread : https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/9561

I'm very surprised to be the only one that seem to experience it. Is it the same for everyone ? Anyone has a fix for it? It is some kind of optimisation that one can disable ?

It's drivin me crazayy!

Comment: Is your file big? (i.e. > 5000 lines) Atom got poor performance on big files. I also prefer other editor when I am dealing with big files.

Comment: no it's not. I just exposed the problem to someone else with the same computer, and he has no fouc at all! am i cursed?